# Could not start backuppc service through puppet

Tags: service, debian, puppet, foreman

I have backuppc which is being handled by puppet and also using foreman. Below is my `init.pp` file :

```
class backuppc::service {
        if $::operatingsystemcodename == 'squeeze' {
                service { 'backuppc' : ensure => running, hasstatus => false, pattern => '/usr/share/backuppc/bin/BackupPC' }
        } else {
                service { 'backuppc' : ensure => running, hasstatus => true }
        }
        service { 'apache2' : ensure => running }
}
```

when I run puppet on node, it throws this reports on foreman :

> class backuppc::service {
>           if $::operatingsystemcodename == 'squeeze' {
>                   service { 'backuppc' : ensure => running, hasstatus => false, pattern => '/usr/share/backuppc/bin/BackupPC' }
>           } else {
>                   service { 'backuppc' : ensure => running, hasstatus => true }
>           }
>           service { 'apache2' : ensure => running }
>   }
>
> change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[backuppc]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/backuppc start' returned 1: Starting backuppc...2016-05-31 17:13:25 Another BackupPC is running (pid 6731); quitting...

node is running with `debain squeeze 6.0.10`.
any help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[backuppc]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/backuppc start' returned 1: Starting backuppc...2016-05-31 17:13:25 Another BackupPC is running (pid 6731); quitting...

... means that puppet attempted to start BackupPC, with `/etc/init.d/backuppc start`, which found that the process was already running. This indicates that puppet is *incorrectly* determining the status of the BackupPC service.

I can't find a reference to a facter fact named `operatingsystemcodename` in the source. Does foreman provide this variable, or are you defining it elsewhere? Perhaps you meant [`lsbdistcodename`](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/1.7/core_facts.html#lsbdistcodename) instead?

If so, and `$::operatingsystemcodename` is undefined, your conditional will always fall through to the `else` branch, and the resource will be defined with [`hasstatus => true`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service-attribute-hasstatus). Puppet will attempt to use `/etc/init.d/backuppc status` to check if the service is running. Therefore, if the init script's `status` action is broken in some way (by always returning a non-0 exit code, for example) puppet will attempt to start the service on every agent run.

---

So first things first, I'd verify that `$::operatingsystemcodename` returns 'squeeze' on the node in question.

If not, I'd check the exit code of `/etc/init.d/backuppc status` under its various states, returning zero when started and non-zero when stopped.

If on the other hand `$::operatingsystemcodename` is undefined, or some unexpected value, then I'd choose another expression to use in the `if` statement. In this case, you'll also want to verify that the [`pattern` attribute](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service-attribute-pattern) is correct by inspecting the process table while the BackupPC service is running.

---

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can provide a value for the [`status` attribute](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service-attribute-status), containing a custom command used by puppet to check the status of the BackupPC service. I would expect something like `status => 'pgrep -f BackupPC` to work well enough. Although, puppet is already doing almost exactly this in ruby code, so I wouldn't expect it to solve you problem.

While a bit dated [this blog post](https://www.devco.net/archives/2009/08/19/tips_and_tricks_for_puppet_debugging.php) covers some general tips for troubleshooting puppet.

Comment: yes, `operatingsystemcodename` provided by foreman. `/etc/init.d/backuppc status` doesn't supported in `backuppc 3.1.0-9.1` so `hasstatus => true` is not worth using it.

Comment: In that case, if you're certain that `operatingsystemcodename` is returning 'squeeze', I would look more closely at the `pattern` attribute in the first conditional branch. When `hasstatus => false` and no `status` attribute is provided, puppet will try to match the value of the `pattern` attribute in the process table (see https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#service-attribute-pattern).

Comment: On the other hand, if you're not certain that `operatingsystemcodename` returns 'squeeze', I'd stick a `notify { "squeeze detected? ${::operatingsystemcodename}": }` somewhere in your code. I'm not particularly familiar with foreman, it may provide a more convenient way to determine which conditional branch is followed. Not sure.

Comment: yes I am certain about `operatingsystemcodename`, foreman returns 'squeeze', I have tested it in my development environment.

Comment: do you think something is fishy with my `pattern` ?

Comment: @arzyfex, yes that would be my best guess based on the information available. `pattern` is used in a regex match against the process table, so maybe try simplifying it, instead of providing the full path? Also, it's worth checking the output of `ps -ef | grep -i backup`, or similar, to confirm you're using an appropriate name for the process.

Comment: Here's the source code that checks the process table, in case that's helpful: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/3.x/lib/puppet/provider/service/base.rb#L16-L30

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113475/discussion-between-arzyfex-and-marty).

Comment: I have checked `ps -ef | grep -i backup` it's the same as I have used in `pattern` clause.

Comment: @arzyfex, Please see my most recent edit. I'm not sure I can help you further, as you'll need to do some troubleshooting on your own. To the best of my knowledge, the two issues I covered in my answer are the only ones I can think would exhibit the behavior you described, but I don't have  a foreman or BackupPC installation to test with. Good luck!